# Issue with center widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I faced error when I write Center widget in Windows 10 the error message says:

> "1 required arguments expected, but 0 to be found."

An interesting thing happened, when I copied my code and put it in my Linux pc it was working fine but on Windows, it wasn't.

**Source code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child:Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.deepPurple,
    ));

  }
}
```

**Flutter doctor:**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.590], locale en-GB)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.2)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted

Comment: I tried this solution , message " fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git "

Comment: Are you sure xou run the command in the Flutter install dir? How did you install? You might need to reinstall.

Comment: Also i'm tried to reinstall flutter sdk and still the same error :(

Comment: Can you please check again the commands from my first comment?

Comment: U mean write this commands inside flutter sdk , i did it  and not work :(